# Island under-the-counter refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, kitchen-counters

We recently bought a house that has a free-standing wine fridge placed in a space in the kitchen island (I hesitate to say *installed*).  We also bought this place knowing full well that unit did not work but with an allowance to replace it.

After hitting up a home improvement store, we learned that the appropriate fridge for our needs would be a "built-in" model that vents in the front.  The problem is that we can only find these styles in 15" or 24" models and the space we have is 20" (apparently the typical size for a "free standing" wine fridge).

We really like the beverage center concept but we don't want to waste 5" nor do we want to redo the cabinets for this.

What should we do with the space?

Comment: 15" fridge and store a folding stool in the extra space?

Comment: I believe this falls under the category of "decorating advice": http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 5):

You can get the smaller refrigerator, and use the extra space to create shelves for bootles. this way you could have refrigerated wine and not refrigerator next to each other.

The shelves would be made to hold individual bottles.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

cut two vents in the back of the cabinet: one just under the counter and another just above the molding. then you don't need a front-vent fridge